# async/await and image upload

Tags: javascript, express, file-upload, async-await

I want to create a post and upload an image if it is provided.

If I do upload the image everything works fine but if I don't I get this error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of null
```

I understand it's to do with `async/await` but I do not know how to rewrite it or that the problem is specifically?

```
app.post("/posts/create", async (req, res) => {
    let image = req.files.image; 

    if (image !== null) {
        image.mv(
            path.resolve(__dirname, "public/images", image.name) 
        );
    }

    await Post.create(req.body);
    res.redirect("/");
});
```

Comment: The error means that `req.files` is `null`. You need to check for that being the case and branch accordingly.

Comment: ^^ ...and so you might want `const image = req.files?.image;` (optional chaining) and then `if (image)` (since a valid image won't be falsy, but both `undefined` and `null` are falsy).

Answer (score 0):

That's not because async/await, it is simply because you don't have any .files in your request, so you just need a middleware for handling multipart/form-data like [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer), and then pass the middleware through the app.post so you can access to req.files, if you want to upload that image to a server like cloudinary you can just use [multer-cloudinary-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-storage-cloudinary).